# having an issue with bluetooth connection in android studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

i've been working on this project for the past month, and since it was working well i haven't modified anything in the code, but for some reason, after a few days i discovered that is not longer working, this is the error i'm getting

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)' on a null object reference
```

both bluetooth and admin permissions are there

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

so it should be accessing to my phone bluetooth paired devices, the arduino was already paired with my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it, for some reason, i had to save the name into a variable, which i wasn't doing before, and then call for a comparison, and it worked, but now, i have may issues related with resources and calling for a thread in the main activity, is like if updating the ide ruined my whole project